# how to change part of argument passed to a function in C?

Tags: c, string, loops

I have function

**Oled_logo(const unsigned char *image)**

so if i pass

> unsigned char **giphy_0 []** = {  0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07,
>   0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 };

e.g. -

**Oled_logo(giphy_0);**

*it works*

but i got 14 such images naming **giphy_0 ,giphy_1 ... giphy_14**

so i want to run these one by one to get an animation

i just want to pass arguments to Oled_logo like Oled_logo(giphy_0)  or Oled_log(giphy_1) or Oleg_logo(giphy_2) ,so instead of doing it for 14 times ,i want to call Oled_logo function in loop and change part of argument giphy_imagenumber in loop.

So instead of writing code to call **Oled_logo** function for 14 times ,i want a loop where i pass **giphy_imagenumber** to function **Oled_logo** and this imagenumber is replaced by loop variable ,so i have to write only few lines in a loop.
following i tried

```
unsigned char x[] = "giphy_0";
    volatile unsigned char y ;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int image_gif = 0 ; image_gif<=14;image_gif++)
        {

            x[6] = image_gif + 0x30;

        Oled_logo(x);

        ssd1306_UpdateScreen();
        HAL_Delay(4000);
        }
}
```

No error came ,but output is some garbage

I tried with strcat ,converted loop variable to string and concatanate with giphy_ and passed to Oled_logo function
Same problem

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Remember its a character array so from 0-9 you it will be fine when it is 10,11,12,13 and 14 it will consider special characters from ASCII table.

Comment: I modified your code and tried locally. If you change it like this it will be fine.  std::string s="giphy_"+to_string(image_gif); and then pass the s to Oled_log function. Try out this.

Comment: Variable names only exist at compile-time, so you simply can't solve this in run-time. Is changing the array types an option? This should obviously have been declared as an array of arrays, or an array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: You want an array of pointers to these arrays. Then, you can get a pointer to one of the giphy arrays, based on the number, from the new array.

Comment: @rootconda will it work in C

Answer (score 1):

`{ 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 }`

is different from

`"giphy_0"`

What you are trying to achieve seems wrong or you are missing a piece.

My guess is you want an array like `{ giphy_0, giphy_1, ... }` and then use the index in this array.

Comment: i just want to pass arguments to Oled_logo like Oled_logo(giphy_0)  or Oled_log(giphy_1) or Oleg_logo(giphy_2) ,so instead of doing it for 14 times ,i want to call Oled_logo function in loop and change part of argument giphy_imagenumber in loop

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is pass in a string with the name of the variable in question an expecting the program to automatically replace this string with the contents of the variable of that name.  That's not how C works.

The real problem here is how you've defined the arrays.  Rather than having a set of arrays with names containing the array number:

```
unsigned char giphy_0 [] = { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 };
unsigned char giphy_1 [] = { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 };
unsigned char giphy_2 [] = { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 };
...
unsigned char giphy_14 [] = { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 };
```

Create an array of arrays:

```
unsigned char giphy[][11] = {
    { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 },
    { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 },
    { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 },
    ...
    { 0x80, 0x81, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff, 0 },
};
```

And pass loop through the outer dimension:

```
    for(int image_gif = 0 ; image_gif<=14; image_gif++)
    {
        Oled_logo(giphy[image_gif]);

        ssd1306_UpdateScreen();
        HAL_Delay(4000);
    }
```